# How to jump between functions

Tags: c

I am trying to make a shopping complex but I can't jump between functions
I have tried goto statements, continue everything please help anything will work

This is my Code

```
#include <stdio.h>
int Verify;
struct Worker
{
    int ID;
    int Password;
}i;

void Workers_data()
{
    struct Worker Sahaj;
    struct Worker Sparsh;
    struct Worker Ramu;
    struct Worker Shamu;

    strcpy(Sahaj.ID,1);
    strcpy(Sahaj.Password,951);
    strcpy(Sparsh.ID,2);
    strcpy(Sparsh.Password,223);    
    strcpy(Ramu.ID,3);
    strcpy(Ramu.Password,2334);
    strcpy(Shamu.ID,4);
    strcpy(Shamu.Password,142);
}

void login()
{
    printf("||||||||||||||||Welcome are you a Customer or a Worker|||||||||||||||||||");
    prinf("Press 1 for Worker and 2 for Customer\n")
    scanf("%d",Verify);
    if (Verify = 1)
    {
        goto Batman;
    }
    else if (Verify = 2)
    {
        goto Superman;
    }
    
}

void Batman()
{
    prinf("Please write your id below\n");
    scanf("%d",&i.ID);
    printf("Please write your password below\n");
    scanf("%d",&i.Password);
}
```

please help me
Thanx in advance

Comment: Have you tried just... *calling* the functions? `Batman();`?

Comment: `if (Verify = 1)` --> `if (Verify == 1)`

Comment: You seem to need a good beginner's book.

Comment: This kind of CLI(command line interface) you can use array of function pointers and call that function using user inputted index.

Answer (score 0):

I think in order to move control to other function, you simply need to call it like this:

```
    if (Verify == 1)
    {
        Batman();
    }
    else if (Verify == 2)
    {
        Superman();
    }
```

No need for goto here. But you need to pass argument to function so that it can process the values.

Your code has some problems:

1.) while comparing you're using `=` rather than `==`

2.) `scanf("%d", Verify);` You need to pass address here : `&Verify`

3.) You haven't declared any struct variable/array for taking input. You should also add a variable/array for it where you should take input via scanf in `Batman()`:

```
  i workers[100];
  int nWorkers;
```

4.) Some typos for `printf` method.

5.) Not using `typedef` for creating structure alias:

```
typedef struct Worker
{
    int ID;
    int Password;
}i;
```

6.) Superman() method doesn't seem to be defined anywhere(maybe your code is still WIP). But Batman() can be improved like this:

```
void Batman()
{
    printf("Please write your id below\n");
    scanf("%d",&workers[nWorkers].ID); // Initialize it to zero in main()
    printf("Please write your password below\n");
    scanf("%d",&workers[nWorkers].Password);
    nWorkers++;
}
```

Comment: `if (Verify = 1)`...not at all.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I just answered for that jump . let me update